# common gridview for whole project asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to create a grid view for whole project. (asp.net, c#)

in project contains 10 forms and each forms contains a grid.

i want to make it a (single grid)user-control .

how can i make it. please give some sample source or a reference link

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Web User Control and inlcude that control in your pages. I am not sure why would you want to do so as I believe each form will have its own data (not the same). If the data source are different, you will still have to set the properties in the user control as you would do with the Grid.